# To make cell bold of an excel using Excel.OpenXml.Table

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-table

To make cell bold of an excel using Excel.OpenXml.Table .

The code :

```
 XLTable objXLTable = new XLTable("TEST");

Row<string> objDataRow = new Row<string>(RowType.Data);



for(int i=0; i< 10 ; i++)
{
         Cell<string> c1 = new Cell<string>("Row number " + i.toString());
         Cell<string> c2 = new Cell<string>("tt" );
         Cell<string> c3 = new Cell<string>("bb " );

         objDataRow.Add(c1);
         objDataRow.Add(c2);
         objDataRow.Add(c3);
}

 objXLTable.Add(objDataRow);
```

I want to make c1 cell bold .What i have tried :

```
 Cell<string> c1 = new Cell<string>("Row number " + i.toString(),10);
```

ANd

```
c1.BoldIndex =10 ;
```

But no effect .  c1. style is not there .any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To add a cell value,

Add the string content to the SharedStringTable, and use the index of that item as

`cellvalue.text = index`

To make a cell bold:

`StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U`

You can add it to:

```
Cell cell1 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "A1", StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U, DataType = CellValues.SharedString };
```